# Pagination in a Large List of Data - Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, pagination, paging

I would like to have pagination in a large list of data. I have been searching for pagination in Flutter, but all of them are showing the way to use load more or lazy loading, but I would like to load data page by page. So, if I have a 100 data list, on the first page there will be a list of data from 1-10, second page: 11-20, ... Are there any resources available for me to do that?

Comment: *"Is there any resources available for me to do that ?"* - yes, `PaginatedDataTable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have given you a complete example. If you have any problem do let me know. Also, you need to check if the `page is not < 0` and  `> max available page`.

Check demo on the action: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=45a5415abd0ae0fa87caac53e3b7f3e3

Gist: https://gist.github.com/omishah/45a5415abd0ae0fa87caac53e3b7f3e3

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<int> _data = List.generate(100, (i) => i); // generate a sample data ( integers ) list of 100 length
  int _page = 0; // default page to 0
  final int _perPage = 10; // per page items you want to show

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataToShow =
        _data.sublist((_page * _perPage), ((_page * _perPage) + _perPage)); // extract a list of items to show on per page basis

    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Row(children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => {
            setState(() {
              _page -= 1;
            })
          },
          child: const Text('Prev'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => {
            setState(() {
              _page += 1;
            })
          },
          child: const Text('Next'),
        )
      ]),
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: dataToShow.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${dataToShow[index]}'),
          );
        },
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```